# Get sum from multiply rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sum

How can I take the sum of more than one row in my database?

Currently I have this:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(alertpay_cashout,paypal_cashout,okpay_cashout) AS value_sum FROM users'); 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); $sum = $row['value_sum'];
```

As you can see, I wish to get the sum from alertpay_cashout, paypal_cashout and okpay_cashout from all my users.

The above code does not work.

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add them with `+`

```
SELECT SUM(alertpay_cashout + paypal_cashout + okpay_cashout) AS value_sum 
FROM users
```

Comment: Tried this. Gave me this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT SUM(alertpay_cashout + paypal_cashout + okpay_cashout) AS value_sum FROM' at line 1

Comment: @oliverbj: Since the error show right from the beginning of your select statement, there must be something else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (SUM(alertpay_cashout) + SUM(paypal_cashout) + SUM(okpay_cashout))  `SUM` 
FROM users
```